# converting a .scala project definition using Project.configs to build.sbt

Tags: sbt

I am trying to convert a build definition from Scala to build.sbt

In the Scala definition, I have something like:

```
  lazy val ComponentTest = config("componenttest") extend Test
  val componentTests = inConfig(ComponentTest)(Defaults.testTasks) ++ Seq(
    testOptions in ComponentTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(componentTestFilter))
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies ++ testDependencies)
    .settings(...)
    .configs(ComponentTest)
    .settings(componentTests: _*)

  private def componentTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "CT"
```

I have not found out how to migrate the Project.configs(ComponentTest) to a build.sbt

The only solution I found was much more complex:

```
lazy val ComponentTest = config("componenttest") extend Test

inConfig(ComponentTest)(Defaults.testSettings)

javaSource in ComponentTest := (javaSource in Test).value

scalaSource in ComponentTest := (scalaSource in Test).value

configuration in ComponentTest := (configuration in Test).value

testOptions in ComponentTest := (testOptions in Test).value

testOptions in Test += Tests.Filter(unitFilter)

testOptions in ComponentTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(componentTestFilter))

def componentTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "CT"
```

Defining all settings again (javaSource, scalaSource...) does not feel right.

Is there something better?
Or should I mix .scala and .sbt definitions?
Or stick to .scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to your project using `project` macro.

```
lazy val main = project.in(file(".")).configs(ComponentTest)

lazy val ComponentTest = config("componenttest") extend Test

inConfig(ComponentTest)(Defaults.testTasks) ++ Seq(
  testOptions in ComponentTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(componentTestFilter))
)

def componentTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "CT"
```

As for your question if you should mix both `.scala` and `.sbt`. I think it's a valid approach when needed. The `build.sbt` has it's [limitations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html#sbt-vs-scala-build-definition), e.g. code in different `.sbt` files is not shared, and writing complex builds is inconvenient (you have to remember to add extra line after each statement and to keep all expressions together).

I would say you should stick to whatever suits you.